# Script Block powershell remote MSI Installation

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, powershell-2.0

Hi I was trying to execute MSI from build machine A(cttfs) and install that MSI on Machine B(c2devint); output is website on Machine B.

Please help me fixing the powershell script which is on Machine A with MSI installer.This script is run from Machine A

```
$cred = Get-Credential username
$session = new-PSSession -name c2devint -credential $cred
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i C:\DailyBuild\DirectMSI.msi INSTALLLOCATION=D:\Websites\DirectDevInt ENVPROPERTY=DEV /qb" -Wait} -ComputerName c2devint}
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Here is the error

```
 Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
    At line:3 char:44
    + Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Command <<<<  -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i C:\DailyBuild\DirectMSI.msi INSTALLLOCATION=D:\Websites\DirectDevInt ENVPROPERTY=DEV /qb" -Wait} -ComputerName c2devint}
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

And also please help me how to pass username & pwd to this script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you created a PSSession, use the `-ComputerName` parameter on [`New-PSSession`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849717.aspx).

```
Parameter Set: ComputerName
New-PSSession [[-ComputerName] <String[]> ] [-ApplicationName <String> ] [-Authentication <AuthenticationMechanism> ] [-CertificateThumbprint <String> ] [-ConfigurationName <String> ] [-Credential <PSCredential> ] [-EnableNetworkAccess] [-Name <String[]> ] [-Port <Int32> ] [-SessionOption <PSSessionOption> ] [-ThrottleLimit <Int32> ] [-UseSSL] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Move the`-Session` parameter on [`Invoke-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) outside the scriptblock:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock `
    {Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i C:\DailyBuild\DirectMSI.msi INSTALLLOCATION=D:\Websites\DirectDevInt ENVPROPERTY=DEV /qb" -Wait}
```

Then remove `-ComputerName` paremeter on `Invoke-Command` since you are using the `Session` paremeter set.

```
Parameter Set: Session
Invoke-Command [[-Session] <PSSession[]> ] [-ScriptBlock] <ScriptBlock> [-ArgumentList <Object[]> ] [-AsJob] [-HideComputerName] [-InputObject <PSObject> ] [-JobName <String> ] [-ThrottleLimit <Int32> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: Hi Andy i think you have given below one as your answer; but this installs  MSI which is on Machine A onto Machine A rather than Machine B. I want install MSI on remote machine B. "Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock `
    {Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i C:\DailyBuild\DirectMSI.msi INSTALLLOCATION=D:\Websites\DirectDevInt ENVPROPERTY=DEV /qb" -Wait}"

Comment: @Chatrapathi no, it should run msiexec remotely on machine B.

Comment: But in this statement we don't have specified any -computername and its credentials. Can you please give me the statement with it."Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ` {Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i C:\DailyBuild\DirectMSI.msi INSTALLLOCATION=D:\Websites\DirectDevInt ENVPROPERTY=DEV /qb" -Wait}"

Comment: I think this is statement you are asking me to run. I ran below stmt;and it was running for ever not doing anything. After I ran it just asked my pwd of the username.Can I give pwd in the statement ;if so how can i provide it in the statement. /***************/ $cred = Get-Credential c2\chennamc
$session = new-PSSession -ComputerName c2devint -credential $cred
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/I C:\DailyBuild\DirectMSI.msi INSTALLLOCATION=D:\Websites\DirectDevInt ENVPROPERTY=DEV /qb" -Wait}
Remove-PSSession $session

Comment: @Chatrapathi read the section [Establish a Persistent Connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx)

Comment: Hi Andy for some reason the ps1 script on MachineA is installing MSI on Machine A itself and creating out put of MSI at INSTALLLOCATION=D:\Websites\DirectDevInt on Machine A instead of Machine B.